# Xcode 7 where is xcshareddata

Tags: xcode, version-control

I am trying to remove an unwanted working copy from a project's source control, but when I look in:

myProject(show package contents) > myProject.xcworkspace(show package contents)

I see a contents.xcworkspacedata file and the xcuserdata folder.

Why am I not seeing the xcshareddata file?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you don't see it is because none of your project settings have been shared. See the image below shows where you would share a project Schema for everyone else working on the project. If you do share project settings then the xcshareddata directory gets created at the following path and for example any shared schemas you have created will appear in the directory.:

```
yourAppProject.xcodeproj/xcshareddata
```

[image]